# Как создать массив из определенных значений вложенного словаря?

Tags: python, массивы, dataframe, словари

У меня есть вложенный словарь:

```
{pers:{sigs:[A, 1, 6, 3]},
      {rets:[A, 5, 9, 2]},
      {kols:[D, 1, 3, 7]}}
```

Как мне создать массив или датафрейм состоящий только из вторых элементов вложенных словарей `sigs`, `rets`, `kols`?

Comment: Что то я не вишу словаря.

Comment: Сейчас это некорректная структура - строки без кавычек, словари не в списке, а сами по себе как-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исправить структуру на корректную, то, наверное, так:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = \
{'pers':[
    {'sigs':['A', 1, 6, 3]},
    {'rets':['A', 5, 9, 2]},
    {'kols':['D', 1, 3, 7]}
]}

df = pd.DataFrame({k:v for d in data['pers'] for k,v in d.items()})
```

Тогда в `df`:

```
  sigs rets kols
0   A    A    D
1   1    5    1
2   6    9    3
3   3    2    7
```

**Update**
Я не дочитал задание, если нужны только вторые элементы, то примерно так же:

```py
lst_ = [v[1] for d in data['pers'] for k,v in d.items()]
# [1, 5, 1]
```

Comment: спасибо, а как ограничить  так, чтобы в датафрейме одной колонкой записывались только вторые элементы значения вложенных словарей?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.